# concatenate and add an array of pointers into one index of another array of pointers

Tags: c

Is it possible to concatenate and add an array of pointers into one index of another array of pointers. I'm trying to take the strings inside my *token pointer and make it one string inside the first index of my commands pointer array, so on and so forth

```
            cmd = strtok(str, " ");
            while(n < 5 && (act_token = strtok(NULL, " ")))
            {
                    token[n] = act_token;
                    n++;
            }
            token[n] = NULL;


                    /* Below is where I'm trying to add all the elements of the token array into one index of the comands array */
                    while( z < len ){
                            comands[b] = token[z];
                            z++;
                    }
                    b++;
            }
```

Comment: I'm a little confused as to your goal. If it's to have two strings like "JIM" and "BOB", and then have another string that is "JIMBOB" without duplicating the data, you can't...Well, at least not without creating your own string structure/functions.

Comment: What is going wrong? What isn't working? I can see undefined behavior. If the loop ends because `n>=5` then `token[n] = NULL;` is UB. Also `int len = sizeof(token)/sizeof(token[0]);` wont give the number of tokens (you already have that in `n` don't you?)

Comment: @zzxyz My goal is to take the tokens[0] = "BOB", token[1] = "John" and then add to the comands pointer as comand[0] = "BOB JOHN"

Comment: @John3136 Yeah I realised the len won't give me the number of tokens after I ran it. I already have N. My code works up until the second while loop where I'm achieving  to something like this for example  tokens[0] = "BOB", token[1] = "John" and then add to the comands pointer as comand[0] = "BOB JOHN

Comment: @pennyBoy - `command[0] = malloc(strlen(token[0])+strlen(token[1]) + 1); strcpy(command[0], token[0]); strcat(command[0], token[1]);`  You should probably write a function that does that for an arbitrary number of tokens, but that's the basic procedure..

Comment: @zzxyz Oh wow. I would have to manually do all that stuff? Do you know if there's another way I could do this whole thing?

Comment: @pennyBoy In C? no. @zzxyz has what you need. In C++ you could user strings - but the the whole `strtok()` approach would probably be obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

I feel your pain.  String handling is very bad in C, and almost as bad in C++. 
 However, once you write the function, all you have to do is call it...

```
char *GetStringFromStringArray(const char**sourceStrings, size_t nCount)
{
  char *destString = NULL;
  size_t destLength = 1; //start with room for null-terminator
  if (nCount == 0)
    return destString;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < nCount; i++)
    destLength += strlen(sourceStrings[i]);
  destString = (char*)malloc(destLength);
  strcpy(destString, sourceStrings[0]);
  for (size_t i = 1; i < nCount; i++)
    strcat(destString, sourceStrings[i]);
  return destString;
}

int main()
{
  char *tokens[10] = { "bob", "jim", "hank" };
  char *destStrings[2];
  destStrings[0] = GetStringFromStringArray((const char**)tokens, 2);
  destStrings[1] = GetStringFromStringArray((const char**)&tokens[1], 2);
  free(destStrings[0]);
  free(destStrings[1]);
}
```

The way I initialized `tokens` is not ok, by the way.  Purely for easy example.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a try

Answer (score 2):

To avoid O(n*n) complexity caused by looping a concatenation, in [@zzxyz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52489424/2410359) otherwise good answer, consider copying to  the end of the accumulated destination.

```
char *concat_alloc(const char *token[], size_t n) {
  size_t sum = 1;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    size_t len = strlen(token[i]);
    sum += len;
    if (sum < len) {
      return NULL;  // Too long
    }
  }

  char *dest = malloc(sum);
  if (dest) {
    char *p = dest;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      size_t len = strlen(token[i]);
      memcpy(p, token[i], len);
      p += len;  // advance to the end
    }
    *p = '\0';
  }
  return dest;
}
```

Comment: upvoted, because you certainly have a point (and I should've used `size_t`).  Though I would say, particularly given the OP's comfort level with pointers and strings, that this might be a case of premature optimization.

Comment: "premature optimization" readily applies when trying to make code _linearly_ faster such that O() remains the same.  This answer differs. This takes the good-enough for-learners O(n*n) approach and brings it to O(n).  True, it may be beyond OP today, yet not _premature optimization_.

Comment: Yeah, it's difficult.  I intensely dislike not using standard routines (`strcat` here) when they are sufficient, but my answer would be catastrophically slow for (very) large collections of strings.  I'd certainly use your answer for a string library, probably mine for a local function (that deals with known quantities)